# How to localize the dependencies of a package in node_modules

Tags: npm, frontend, node-modules, pnpm

Here is my project's package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react-infinite-viewer": "^0.28.0"
}
```

Dependencies of this package: `myproject -> react-infinite-viewer -> infinite-viewer -> gesto`

The actual situation of the project, there are actually more than one package that directly or indirectly depends on gesto. This means it's a `multiple packages dependencies on gesto at different levels`

I have tried this way

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react-infinite-viewer": "^0.28.0",
  "gesto":"file:packages/gesto"
}
```

This approach only installs the modified code in the project's node_modules. This means that I can use the modified code in my project, but react-infinite-viewer will still use the original code.

```
myproject
  ->node_modules
    ->react-infinite-viewer
        ->node_modules
            ->infinite-viewer
                ->node_modules
                    gesto // here is still use the original code
  ...
  ->gesto // here using the modified code
```

should I use pnpm or lerna to solve this problem?

When using `yarn`/`pnpm i`/`yarn add xxx`..., all packages that dependencies on gesto use the modified gesto code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by configuring `resolutions`

if use npm,change the package.json:

```
{
    ...
      "scripts": {
          "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
      },
     "resolutions": {
          "gesto":"file:packages/gesto"
     }
}
```

if use yarn , it will be easier than npm

```
{
    ...
     "resolutions": {
          "gesto":"file:packages/gesto"
     }
}
```

Yarn's selective dependency resolution feature is the default functionality of npm-force-resolutions. You do not need to install npm-force-resolutions to use it.
[Selective dependency resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)